# Weird image behavior between FF and IE

Tags: website, image

Anyone know why [this link](http://blaclabelpremium.com/images/products/BL0609/tss-02-white-f-s.jpg) displays fine in FF but not in IE?  One thing I notice in FF is that it first displays the path and then the image loads.  I haven't fully investigated this yet, so I don't know if there's an HttpHandler registered for images which is causing issues.  But I wanted to check here first if anyone knew something right away.

This is an off-the-shelf storefront, "BV Commerce Software".

Thanks.

Comment: Half a meg for a 100px image? Wow, someone loves their DPI!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF displays the image path because the image is quite large and takes a time to load.

It apparently contains a lot of metadata; if I open the JPEG in Gimp and resave as JPEG, the 576 kBof the original shrink to 10 kB. Strip out the additional data, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because the image is encoded in the CMYK colorspace. Just open it in a graphic editor and save as RGB.